# Remove item from list using a string name

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, variables

I want to know if there's a way that I can change what list an item gets removed from depending on something beforehand.

```
list0 = ("1", "2", "3")
list1 = ("4", "5", "6")
var = randint(0,1)
if var == 0:

    list = "list0"
else:

    list = "list1"

list.pop(0)
print(list)
```

*basically from what I understand, python thinks I'm trying to 'pop' the 1st item from the string "list0//list1" (depending on what's chosen), rather than the list. Is there a way that I can set the variable treat it as one of my list names? Thanks!

Comment: Don't name a variable after a Python built-in: you've now overwritten the built-in type (and function) `list`.

Comment: Use a dict, with keys "list0" and "list1" (or probably just keys "0" and "1"; and going from there, you can create a list of tuples, so list0 becomes `mylist[0]` and list1 `mylist[1]`.

Comment: Note that your lists are tuples, which are *immutable*. You can't change them, so calling `.pop` will result in a error (in fact, the `pop` method does not exist for tuples). Turn your tuples into lists first if you want to modify them.

Comment: Finally, why not simply use `if var == 0: list0.pop() ; else: list1.pop()`.

Comment: I have many different lists (9), and I'd rather not execute a whole lot of code (represented by my one line of list.pop) while checking each one. Thanks though, I'll give it a try!

Comment: See the comment about using a dict or a list of lists. If you use `var = randint(0, 9)`, for example, you can use `var` directly as an index.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a variable name in your program and data.

You can't (easily) match data and variable names from your program.

You can use a mapping to match data:

```
lists = {0: ["1", "2", "3"],
         1: ["4", "5", "6"]}
var = randint(0, 1)
lst = lists[var]  
lst.pop(0)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Note that this example uses tuples (as in the question), but that will cause an `AttributeError` for `.pop()`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
(list1 if var else list0).pop(0)
```

Mind that `list0` and `list1` must be lists and not tuples: tuples are immutable. So you should change your code in this way:

```py
list0 = ["1", "2", "3"]
list1 = ["4", "5", "6"]
```